# Laravel auth filters based on context

Tags: php, laravel

With laravel we have a few auths setup for us which we can control in the routes file or setup in the controller constructor however I need to find a better way of doing this, and not sure if a route can handle it?

With my users, I allow themselves and the admin to edit them. So my controller looks like this.

```
function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    if(!Auth::user()->isAdmin() && $user->id != Auth::user()->id)
    {
        return Redirect::route('users.index')->withError('Unable to access that user');
    }
    return View::make('users.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

which is ok, but then on my update code I also have to do the same auth/user check to make sure a user or admin can only make changes to themselves.

So we get a double up, in some controllers this is repeated 3 times. Another example of context would be a forum post, the person who posted it or the admin can edit it.

Is there a way with route filters to handle doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be of use to you, I have a similar problem in my application where a user can only access their own user profile, but management can access anyone's.

My routes look like:

```
Route::get('user_profile/{user_id?}', array('as' => 'user_profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@get_user_profile'))->where(array('user_id' => '[0-9]+', 'tab' => '[A-Za-z]+'))->before('auth');
Route::when('user_profile/*', 'management');
```

This applies a management filter if the user attempts to go to a specific user, it defaults to their own profile if no ID is given.

```
Route::filter('management', function()
{
    if(Helper::managementStatus() === NOT_MANAGEMENT)
        return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('flash_error', 'You must be logged in as a manager to view this page!');

});
```

Alternatively you could create a filter something like:

```
Route::filter('management', function()
{
    $user = User::findOrFail(Input::get('user_id'));
    if(!Auth::user()->isAdmin() && $user->id != Auth::user()->id)
    {
        return Redirect::route('users.index')->withError('Unable to access that user');
    }
}
```

And then just apply that filter to the relevant routes.

I hope that's helpful.